# Can't push to remote branch after rebase with master?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push, remote-branch

So I have used `git rebase origin/main` on my branch - but I want to push these changes to my remote branch. However, whenever I try to use `git push -f origin name_of_branch` I get the following:

```
    ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have pushed to this branch before so I know the remote exists. I just want to update it with the changes of my rebase. I got the idea of using force push from other stack overflow threads but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone got any ideas ? I just want to update the remote branch with the changes of the rebase. thank you

Comment: Do you have permission? git doesn't think you do

Comment: It's a problem related to permissions (assuming the repo is there, indeed), not with rebase

Answer (score 1):

If you have pushed to this branch before (without -f) and it worked, it seems like the branch is protected against rewrites, which is a common strategy and good practice for main branches (like `master` or `main`) as rewriting it would affect anyone basing their work on it.

What you probably want to often do is pull new changes without rebase and then you won't have that problem. But if you really want to rewrite it you need permission to do it. Assuming you do have it, you can find settings to add/remove protection for branches in the admin settings of any usual version control provider (github, bitbucket, gitlab, etc).

---

**How to undo a rebase on a branch that cannot be rewritten**

There are several ways you can do this depending on your case, but the next commands should be useful for most scenarios:

`git reflog` - to see all the commits your HEAD has pointed to (useful to see the situation before the rebase, as you can do `git log <hash>` for the last hash before the rebase and you'll see every local commit of work that you don't want to lose).

`git reset --hard <hash>` - to reset the branch to any point in history, for example to the situation before the rebase or to the remote version, depending on how you want to approach it

`git cherry-pick <hash>` - to apply a single commit in the current branch

Assuming you know the basics of creating/removing branches and commits, with those commands you can restore the situation to the state before the rebase.

For example, you can move your local work to a temporary branch, recreate the branch you rebased resetting it to the remote version and then cherry pick each valuable commit from the temporary branch.

Or if you took note of all the valuable commits after a `git reflog`, you could simply reset the branch to the state before the rebase and then cherry-pick those commits.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I don't think I have access to admin settings, so what would you advise I do ? Should I be pulling from main and then merging ? What commands should I be using exactly in that case ? I don't want to mess things up anymore. Thank you again

Comment: @lameprogrammer01 speak to the owners of the repo. There are no git commands that can get around protections.

Comment: @lameprogrammer01 then you should never rewrite the branch. Always bring changes from it with `git pull`, not `git rebase` nor `git pull --rebase`. To fix your current situation, one option would be to move your local work to a different branch (`git checkout -b temporal`), delete `main` in local and recreate it again (`git branch -D main` and `git checkout main`), and then cherry-pick there any commits that you had in the temporal branch to reproduce your work in `main`. Then push `main`, and never again rebase it from the remote.

Comment: I updated my answer to include some useful commands to undo the local rebase.

Comment: @Pepe Doval what do you mean by protected against rewrites exactly? Because I have pushed to the branch multiple times before, maybe I am confusing myself

Comment: Protected against rewrites means you can push new commits to the branch (write) but not modify anything that has been pushed already (rewrite). A local rebase changes the git history (as commits are inmutable) so the branch is rewritten from the point where you rebased (that's why you need -f to republish it). Shared branches shouldn't be rewritten as you will affect other developers, and that's why they tend to be protected against it.